# customizing terminal ssh shell

Tags: shell, terminal, gnu-screen, byobu

The other day I saw someone connected to an ssh shell with status bars on the bottom (Mac OS X Terminal) of the terminal. It has things such as upload rate, memory usage, time, current username, and some other stuff.

I'd like to know how I can replicate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He was probably using [Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu):

[image]